# Entity Framework: How to select nested entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

my entity hierarchy is Customer > Address > Contact. so i use this code to iterate in contact details.

```
Contacts CurrentContacts = null;

foreach (var existingContacts in existingCustomer.Addresses.Select(a => a.Contacts.Where(cc=> cc.ContactID==5)))
{
    CurrentContacts = existingContacts;
}
```

but this line `CurrentContacts = existingContacts;` throwing error

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'EFTest.Contacts'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)

what is my mistake. `existingContacts` will have contacts related data and `CurrentContacts` is a variable of contact type.

so please tell me how could i do it.

Comment: What is `Contacts` type? Can you please post the class code?

Comment: issue sorted.......thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have two problems, but without seeing how the `Contacts` type is defined it's just a guess.

As @Taemyr points out, you need to use `SelectMany` instead of `Select` to flatten the collection of collections.

But unless `Contacts` is inherited from `List<EFTest.Contacts>` you still aren't going to be able to do the assignment, you need to change your variable declaration to:

```
IEnumerable<Contacts> CurrentContacts = null;
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  If `Adress.Contacts` has type `IEnumerable<Contacts>` the `Customer.Adresses.SelectMany(a=>a.Contacts)` will be an `IEnumerable<Contacts>` and the individual elements, which you get at in the `foreach`, will be `Contacts`

Answer (score 0):

Use `SelectMany` instead of `Select`.

`Select` projects each individual element and does nothing to the rest of the enumerable
.
So `Addresses.Select(a=>a.Contacts.Where(...))` is an enumerable of whatever `Address.Contacts.Where(...)` is. Ie. you get an enumerable of enumerables.

To get a single enumerable you need to flatten this list.  Which is what `SelectMany` does.

That said even

```
foreach (var existingContacts in <some enumerable>)
{
    CurrentContacts = existingContacts;
}
```

Looks strange.  Unless there are other logic in the loop you could replace the loop with;

```
CurrentContacts= <some enumerable>.LastOrDefault();
```

And if you don't actually care which Contact you use, as long as it has ContactID=5;

```
CurrentContacts= <some enumerable>.FirstOrDefault();
```